# Fleshing out a proof that $\phi$ is dominant iff $\phi^*$ is injective.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, proof-explanation, zariski-topology

*This is a [solution-verification](/questions/tagged/solution-verification)/[proof-explanation](/questions/tagged/proof-explanation) question, since I have a proof that I need to flesh out; I am unsure of a couple of steps.*

### The Details:

Most of the terminology here is given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4559631/104041) of mine.

A morphism $\phi:X\to Y$ of affine varieties is *dominant* if $\phi(X)$ is dense in $Y$, *i.e.*, $\overline{\phi(X)}=Y$ in the Zariski topology.

### The Proof in Question:

We have

$$\begin{align}
\phi^*\text{ is injective}&\iff
\ker(\phi^*)=\{0\}\\
&\iff \forall f\in k[Y](\phi^*(f)=0\iff f=0)\\
&\iff \forall f\in k[Y](f\circ\phi=0\iff f=0)\\
&\stackrel{(1)}{\iff} \mathcal I(\phi(X))=\{0\}\\
&\stackrel{(2)}{\iff }\overline{\phi(X)}=Y\\
&\iff \phi\text{ is dominant.}
\end{align}$$

### The Problem:

> How do $(1)$ and $(2)$ hold?

### Thoughts:

I think $(2)$ holds by taking $\mathcal V$ of both sides in the forward direction, recognising that $\mathcal V(\mathcal I(Z))=\overline Z$; conversely, I think we use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

I have no clue about $(1)$.

### Further Context:

Since I have no clue for $(1)$, to add context, let me answer some of the questions [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28086/104041):

- What are you studying?

A postgraduate research degree in linear algebraic groups. I need to get comfortable with algebraic geometry.

- What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise?

My supervisor set me this question a few weeks ago. The proof above is largely my own, although the things I am not sure about are based on Springer's book, *"Linear Algebraic Groups (Second Edition)"*.

- What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with?

See the following questions:

[Understanding $\mathcal V(I)$, $\mathcal I(X)$, and their relationship to each other.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540881/104041)

[A morphism of affine varieties $\phi: X\to Y$ is an isomorphism iff the algebra homomorphism $\phi^*$ is an isomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4559631/104041)

- What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else?

I would prefer an explanation, please, of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

- Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Yes, but I would need much more time than I have.

---

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About (2): Actually there's a version of the Hilbert Nullstellensatz that holds for ideals in the coordinate ring of an affine variety, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4255135/348926) for details.

About (1): $\mathcal I(\phi(X))$ is the ideal of all functions $f \in k[Y]$ that vanish on $\phi(X)$, i.e. by definition we have $$\forall f \in k[Y]: f\in \mathcal I (\phi(X)) \Leftrightarrow f(\phi(X))=\{0\}$$

But $f(\phi(X))=0$ means that $f(\phi(x))=0$ for all $x \in X$ which is equivalent to saying that $f \circ \phi$ is the zero function in $k[X]$. That's because in the coordinate ring $k[X]$ we take a quotient of the polynomial ring by the functions that vanish identically on $X$, which is exactly the case for $f \circ \phi$ here. Thus we have, without any condition on $\phi$

$$\forall f \in k[Y]: f \in \mathcal I(\phi(X)) \Leftrightarrow f \circ \phi=0$$

Now to say that $\mathcal I(\phi(X))=\{0\}$ is precisely to say that $\forall f \in k[Y]: f \in \mathcal I(\phi(X)) \Leftrightarrow f=0$. If we combine this with the equivalence above, we get (1).

Comment: You skip over a step--just because a polynomial evaluates to 0 on each point of its domain does not make it the zero polynomial!

Comment: @Michael thank you for the comment. You're completely correct. I shall edit accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is better to write things down a bit more verbosely.

Suppose that $\phi : X\longrightarrow Y$ is dominant so that $\phi(X)$ is dense in $Y$. The map $k[Y] \longrightarrow k[X]$ is given by the pullback along $\phi$, and if $f \in k[Y]$ and vanishes on $\phi(X)$, then it vanishes on its closure, which is $Y$, since $V(f)$ is closed and $\phi(X)\subseteq V(f)$. Hence, $f$ is the zero element in $k[Y]$ and $\phi^*$ is injective.

Conversely, suppose that $\phi^*$ is injective, so that if $f\in k[Y]$ vanishes on $\phi(X)$ then $f$ vanishes on all of $Y$. This means that $I(\phi(X))$, the ideal of polynomials that vanish on $\phi(X)$, is just the zero ideal $0$. But since [$V(I(-))$ is the closure operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2290037/zariski-closure-of-a-set-using-the-topological-definition-of-closure), we have that $$ \overline{\phi(X)} = V(I(\phi(X))) =  V(0) = Y.$$

Comment: You skip over a step a little prematurely in your proof of the converse: note that a nonzero function can vanish on a finite set.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure what you mean. Perhaps you protest the conclusion that $I(\phi(X)) = 0$?

Comment: There's another subtle point here: the argument that a function vanishes on a subset also vanishes on the closure is not purely topological, i.e. it doesn't follow from continuity alone, because the Zariski topology is not Hausdorff in general. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543962/348926) for a typical statement one might try to use to give a purely topological argument.) Of course, this is easy to fix, because vanishing sets are closed by definition, but I felt like it's worth pointing it out, because the way you phrased it made it seem like a topological argument.

Comment: @LukasHeger Edited that bit. I am still not sure what Michael is getting at...

Comment: @Pedro If I understand Michael correctly, then the issue is this: suppose that $f$ is represented by some polynomial, then we have shown that $f$ is zero evalueted on the set $Y$. This doesn't make $f$ the zero polynomial. Of course the solution to this is in some sense tautological: in $k[Y]$ we quotient out by $\mathcal I(Y)$, so in some sense "the missing step" is just quoting the definition of $k[Y]$

Comment: @LukasHeger Well, when I say zero I mean zero in $k[Y]$. I thought this was more or less clear.

Comment: @Pedro I agree that it's a bit pedantic, but at this level, it can't hurt to be a bit pedantic if it helps to clear some confusions

Comment: I find this discussion helpful. Thank you :)